# Thread Sequencing In Java.

Tags: java, multithreading

In java, how do we do this:

1. Many threads created and writes to a single file.
2. Since any thread can write to that file ( by acquiring the lock) the order of thread writing is gone.

The the number of threads created will be more than 40. How to dump the threads provided their sequence is not affected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We **don’t** do this. If you don’t want concurrency, don’t use threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you description, the simplest solution is to have the threads save their results and have another thread write them in the order you intended. e.g.

```
int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorServer es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++)
     results.add(es.submit(new Callable<String>() {
          public String call() {
              // task which returns a String
          }
     });
try (PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter("output.txt")) {
    for (Future f : results)
        fw.println(f.get());
}
```

As you can see

- The tasks can execute in any order, but the results are written to the file in expected order.
- The number of tasks executed at once is limited to the actual number of logical CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, threads dont actually have an order, so you would need to created some kind of Pool Queue for them programatically.

Though i dont know if Java 1.7 added new things with its java.concurrent Classes.. that may help you with what you want.

But as for Java 1.6 and below, you would have to have a Queue to manage the threads one by one, to maintain actual order that the JVM wont do.